# Strange Link Error With Command-Line Swift Test (May Be Swift Package Manager-Related)

Tags: swift, testing, package, swift-package-manager

I'm developing a set of interlinked SPM modules as a test/demo, and I've run into a strange linker error.

The problem occurs in [this example](https://github.com/LittleGreenViper/SMPArticle-Package_C), which has a `Package.swift` file that looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Package_C",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .tvOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_14),
        .watchOS(.v5)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Package-C",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["Package_C"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Package_A", url: "git@github.com:LittleGreenViper/SPMArticle-Package_A.git", from: "1.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Package_C",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Package-A", package: "Package_A")
            ],
            path: "src"
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Package_CTests",
            dependencies: [
                "Package_C"
            ],
            path: "test"
        )
    ]
)
```

The package builds fine with `swift build`, and everything works great, when run from Xcode.

The issue happens when I run `swift test`. I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_$s9Package_CAAV6indentABSi_tcfC", referenced from:
      _$s14Package_CTests4testC0C7QuicklyyyFSSyKXEfu_ in Package_CTests.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[4/5] Linking Package_CPackageTests
```

It looks like `Package_C` is not being linked in, but everything appears to be absolutely kosher (also, remember that everything else works fine. `swift test` is the only place this fails).

It should be noted that [this project](https://github.com/LittleGreenViper/SPMArticle-Package_B) works fine, and does almost exactly the same thing.

The only difference that I can see, is the naming conventions of the directories. I'd really hate for that to be the issue, but I'll mess around with that, next.

Can anyone see what I can't see?

***EDITED TO ADD:** I should note that the static/dynamic thing doesn't seem to be the issue. I get the same error, even when I change `Package_C` to static.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. Looks like the issue is that the naming convention needs to be followed.

I switched from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

and it started working. No file contents (other than removing the two `path` arguments from the `Package.swift` file) were changed.

Here is [the new Package.swift file](https://github.com/LittleGreenViper/SMPArticle-Package_C/blob/master/Package.swift):

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Package_C",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .tvOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_14),
        .watchOS(.v5)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Package-C",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["Package_C"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Package_A", url: "git@github.com:LittleGreenViper/SPMArticle-Package_A.git", from: "1.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Package_C",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Package-A", package: "Package_A")
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Package_CTests",
            dependencies: [
                "Package_C"
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```